# What time to leave on last day of internship?

Tags: internship

Some context: I'm an intern at a small Silicon Valley startup. Tomorrow is my last day. My exit meeting with HR is set at 11 am, and I have to turn in all equipment (laptop, badge, etc) then. HR has also planned a pizza party from 12:30 to 1:30 for all the interns. Tomorrow is a Friday, so people tend to leave earlier (4, 5 pm).

I've finished my projects and documentation, and all I have to do is say goodbye to my coworkers.

I get paid on an hourly basis, and I'm getting my final paycheck tomorrow, so the time I leave tomorrow is going to affect how much I get paid. I don't care about the money. My question is, when should I leave for good? Right after the pizza party? At the end of the work day? Somewhere in between?

Comment: That is really up to you, if they are throwing a pizza party most probably they don't mind paying those extra minutes/hours.... however, this also depends on you company, but I suspect you are not going to be paid for those hours. You may be paid hourly but you have a start/end work time

Comment: Right, my question is exactly about that start/end work time. Since I'm paid per hour, would it make sense for me to stick around after all that is done, or does it make more sense for me to take a half day and leave after that party?

Comment: I would go to the party, but I would not hang out too late after it finishes.

Comment: The answer is: ask your supervisor what his expectations are.

Comment: Simply say to your supervisor: "Say, do you want me to clear off after the party, or stay through until 5pm?" {substitute your usual official end time}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**When the party is done.**

HR has already processed you out which means, per their paperwork, you are no longer working there.  It's not uncommon for HR to release employees in the middle of the day but pay them through the end.

The pizza party is a way for the company to close out your time with them and given they have taken your resources (laptop, badge, etc.) you technically can't do any more work.  It's time to say goodbye.

Comment: Make sure you've discussed this with your supervisor - simply disappearing before the official end of the day may end up affecting any reference from the company.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't work, because you've turned in the laptop, then you are probably expected to leave after the party, and only work a half day.

However, at your meeting with HR, you can certainly ask.  If they already have your last paycheck, then they know how many hours they expect you to work.  It will probably become clear in the meeting, but if it is not, then ask.

Comment: See, HR is asking _me_ to fill out how many hours I'll work tomorrow. So it's not up to them per say, it's up to me.

Comment: @jmoon - can you do any work without the equipment?  If not, then hanging around just so you get more money is not professional, and you should put down a half day.  If you can do work and want to do the work and HR and your manager allow it, then go ahead and work the full day.

Comment: I can't really work without the equipment, so I'll probably give myself an hour and a half after the party to say goodbye to everyone before leaving.